# Adding 'Dataviz' to dashboard when deleted by mistake

Tags: dashboard

I mistakenly clicked on the x and removed a dataviz!  How do I get it back as it is no longer showing as available to be added to the Dashboard?

Thanks

Ed

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the "Dataviz" is?  Is it from CiviVisualize?  Or is it a chart from a CiviReport?